# Does bean creation in spring datasource xml open connection to the database?

Tags: java, database, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

In Spring while creating beans in the following way in datasource xml does it also establishes a connection with the database?
If it opens a db connection,then how it get closed?

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin@localhost:1521/myoracledb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
```

Does rs.close();,ps.close(); and conn.close(); in finally block guarantees connection close  where rs is ResultSet object,ps is PreparedStatement  object and conn is Connection object.

I am using normal JDBC(with Spring-Datasource.xml) and springMVC and facing some issue with connection remaining open with the database.

Is there any other way to ensure that database connection remain closed in the process?

Answer (score 1):

First thing

The `datasource` configuration in the `spring-context.xml` provides Simple implementation of the standard `JDBC DataSource interface`, configuring a plain old `JDBC Driver` via `bean properties`, and returning a `new Connection` for every `getConnection` call.

Each time you do a `datasourceObject.getConnection()` it will establish a new connection for you.

Secondly

Use of (`rs.close()`, `ps.close()` and) `conn.close()` in a finally block guarantees connection close.

Yes it does, that is why it is recommended to close the `connection` in the `finally` because even in case of some `Exception` the `finally` block will get execute and release the resources